# log4j+commons-logging migration to Logback

Tags: log4j, runtime, logging, slf4j, logback

We are using log4j+commons-logging in our current projects. Now we are mirgrating from log4j to Logback, so can we just use replace `log4j.properties` with `logback.xml` or we have to convert log4j to SLF4J?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SLF4J and its `log4j-over-slf4j` module.

From [the documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j):

> log4j-over-slf4j
>
> SLF4J ship with a module called `log4j-over-slf4j`. It allows log4j users to migrate existing applications to SLF4J without changing a single line of code but simply by replacing the `log4j.jar` file with `log4j-over-slf4j.jar`, as described below.

You also need Logback behind SLF4J and Logback configuration (`logback.xml`/`logback.groovy` etc.)

A similar module exists for commons-logging also. (See [Gradual migration to SLF4J from Jakarta Commons Logging (JCL)](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jcl-over-slf4j).)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help I kept the code as it is and include log4j-over-slf4j jar in compile path it is compiling fine i add -Dlogback.configurationFile=C:\u001\isuser\tesbea\user_projects\domains\iservices10\resources\logback.xml setDomainEnv.cmd and logback-classic logback-core on classpath but still not getting any logs any suggestion would be appreciate